# !updated new issue! Node JS Read form input with express

Tags: node.js

New Question!

I got the web page to display and was able to retrieve and display the user input.
However, my code only allows one user input, the rest will be undefined if I add another input field in the HTML.
Here is the updated code, which will only display the last name.

```
/*server.js*/
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var formHTML = require('./formHTML');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var html = formHTML.html1;

  res.send(html);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var firstName = req.body.firstName;
  var lastName = req.body.lastName;
  var html = formHTML.html2;

  html = html.replace('firstName', firstName);
  html = html.replace('lastName', lastName);
  res.send(html);
});

app.listen(8080);


/*formHTML.js*/
var html1 = '<form action="/" method="post">' +
  'Enter your first name:' +
  '<input type="text" name="firstrName" placeholder="..." />' +
  '<br>' +
  'Enter your last name:' +
  '<input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="..." />' +
  '<br>' +
  '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
  '</form>';

var html2 = 'Hello: firstName lastName .<br>' + '<a href="/">Try again.</a>';

exports.html1 = html1;
exports.html2 = html2;
```

What can I try to retrieve both user input??
Thanks!

=========================================================================

I have the following code that supposedly open a web page with one user input field, and use express to get and post display the user's input.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var html = '<form action="/" method="post">' +
    'Enter your name:' +
    '<input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="..." />' +
    '<br>' +
    '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
    '</form>';

  res.send(html);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var userName = req.body.userName;
  var html = 'Hello: ' + userName + '.<br>' +
    '<a href="/">Try again.</a>';
  res.send(html);
});

app.listen(80);
```

However, I got the following error and I cannot figure out how to get it to work. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks!

> Thu, 02 Jun 2016 15:10:23 GMT body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use
>   individual json/urlencoded middlewares at server.js:20:9 Thu, 02 Jun
>   2016 15:10:23 GMT body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide
>   extended option at ....\node_modules\body-parser\index.js:105:29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bodyParser()` constructor has been deprecated (details [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/commit/b7420f8dc5c8b17a277c9e50d72bbaf3086a3900)), you need to use these now :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

When `extended` is set to true, it will use the `qs` library for parsing, and when set to false it will use `querystring`. Research the difference between the two to decide which one you want to use, I've always used `qs` without any issues.

Comment: After changing to the above code, I got another error on the bodyParser with "Invalid number of arguments, expected 2...."

Comment: Oh NVM, I guess that error does not affect the functionality. The program still works with the error.

Answer (score 0):

change the :

```
app.use(bodyParser());
```

with :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```